# My Javascript code doesn't work anymore after I wrap it in a self-calling function

Tags: javascript

I see in a lot of code that people wrap everything in a self-calling function so everything stays more or less private. Doing this to my code resulted in it not working anymore.

I Googled a bit about it and saw that it is good practice to place the whole source file in a self-calling function so I decided to try it too. I tried this with my little piece of code and it just doesn't work anymore after doing it.

```
(function($) {
    const auth = firebase.auth();

    function logIn(){
        window.alert("pressed log in button");
        var userEmail = document.getElementById("txtEmail").value;
        var userPass = document.getElementById("txtPassword").value;

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPass).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);
        });
    };
});
```

I expected the code to work but whenever I press the button that calls the logIn function I get the following error message: "Uncaught ReferenceError: logIn is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick". This clearly shows that turning my code into a self-calling function makes it not work anymore.

Comment: Have you tried putting your `click` event handler also within the `(function($) {`?

Comment: The reason the IIFE is considered "good practice" is because it doesn't clutter the global scope with variable names. However, in your case, you have `logIn` used as an `onclick` attribute within your HTML, which means that is _must_ be visible in the global scope, so you cannot use an IIFE.

Comment: @imvain2 I am calling the function from my HTML code with ```onclick="login();"```

Comment: @Pecchy I don't believe there's a `lick` event in the specification... :P

Comment: You are not using `$` anywhere, so there is no need to have it as a parameter. (Or when you do end up using it, be sure to pass it when invoking the function).

Comment: looks like my c key is playing games with me today :) Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I tried firing the event, but it didn't work. Probably because the `login()` function isn't global due to the IIFE, and therefor I can't access it by licking my monitor.

Comment: @Daan I don't believe you'd be able to access any function by licking your monitor :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> after I wrap it in a self-calling function

You haven't wrapped it in an IIFE. You've wrapped it in a function which is never called. To make it an IIFE you need to call it (e.g. with `(whatever_you_want_assigned_to_the_$_argument)` at the end).

> I Googled a bit about it and saw that it is good practice to place the whole source file in a self-calling function

This is because globals are bad. (That's a generalisation).

> Uncaught ReferenceError: logIn is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Since you don't assign any event handlers in your code, presumably your HTML looks like:

```
onclick="logIn()"
```

You are trying to call `logIn`, as a global.

Now, since the whole point of using an IIFE is to **stop using globals**, that doesn't work.

Bind your event handlers with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Getting_Data_Into_and_Out_of_an_Event_Listener), or (since you seem to be using jQuery) the jQuery wrapper around that instead.

```js
(function($) {
    function logIn(){
        window.alert("pressed log in button");
    }
    $("button#logIn").on("click", logIn);
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id=logIn>Log In</button>
```